# Как заполнить рандомными символами строковый массив длиной 5?

Tags: java, строки

Как создать одномерный массив строк, заполненный рандомными символами. Каждая строка имеет длину 5.

Comment: Генерировать `char`ы ( aka `short` ) с помощью `Math.random`, конкатенатить, ???, PROFIT!!!

Comment: @AndreyM, слишком просто. Нужно делать массив, в котором, кроме 5символьных строк точно ничего нет)

Answer (score 1):

Генерирует случайные пятисимвольные строки из символов с кодами от 33 по 126. Там дальше DEL, так что пришлось бы для больших кодов делать другую обработку.

На каждой итерации генерируем случайное число от 33 по 126, приводим к char и создаём символ по коду. Так 5 раз. С помощью StringBuilder собираем строку.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int STR_LENGTH = 5;
    System.out.println("Введите количество случайных строк");
    int n = in .nextInt();
    String[] arr = new String[n];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < STR_LENGTH; j++) {
            char code = (char) (r.nextInt(94) + 33);
            builder.append(Character.toString(code));
        }
        arr[i] = builder.toString();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

другой вариант: можно использовать [Java Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
    char[] chars = IntStream.rangeClosed('А', 'я') // указываем диапазок символов, тут весь русский алфавит
        .mapToObj(c -> "" + (char) c)
        .collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray(); // собираем в массив

    String res = new Random().ints(5, 0, chars.length) // рандомно выбираем 5 чисел от 0 до 64
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(chars[i])). // берем значение из массива
            collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // склеиваем через " ,"
    System.out.println(res);
```

результат

```
У, й, а, Я, Р
х, Л, е, в, Щ
```

Comment: Длина массива `chars` не `66`, а `64`, так что тут не весь алфавит - стоит исправить это в комментариях к коду. Ещё можно сократить код, используя `int[] charCodes = IntStream.rangeClosed('А', 'я').toArray();`, но это уже на любителя.

Comment: спасибо. не проверил длину

Comment: Хороший результат получился.